# Get uri parameter with javascript than return it to new url?

Tags: javascript, parameters, uri

im not that familir with javascript but i need some help . Basically i have this scenario : i want to get a parameter from url , lets say http://mysite1.com/path/#me=VALUE_OF_ME_PARAMETER here also i have a javascript code which redirects to a second site , lets say mysite2.com/path1 , so what i need is when mysite1 redirects to mysite2 i want it also to return http://mysite2.com/path1/#me=VALUE_OF_ME_PARAMETER , where #me parameter value is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to reuse the complete "hash" part of the [`Location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location) (the part after and including `#...`), you can say:

```
window.location = "http://mysite2.com/path1/" + window.location.hash;
```

This will also redirect you to `http://mysite2.com/path1/#me=VALUE_OF_ME_PARAMETER`, if executed from `http://mysite1.com/path/#me=VALUE_OF_ME_PARAMETER`.

Comment: Thank you very much , this worked perfeclty , you're a genius !

Comment: sure i did but it doesnt show as i have low reputation right now .

Answer (score 0):

Check the following code: First you must get the url via window.location.href method. Then I make  a function using regex obj with two arguments. First the url string and second the name of the url parameter that i want to get.

```js
var url_string = "http://localhost:9080/l?state=12345&code=my_code_here";

function getValueUrl(url,name){
   var a=new RegExp(name+'=([^&]+)');
    a=a.exec(url)[1];
      return a;
}

console.log(getValueUrl(url_string, 'code'));
```